# Where to place images in JAR Archetype

Tags: maven

In a typical WAR archetype, this typically ends up in `src/main/webapp`. However, in the case of a typical JAR archetype, there shouldn't be such a folder.

Where would be the better place to put images in a JAR archetype? Thanks.

Comment: src/main/resources, or create your own naming convention ("assets") and configure it as something that should go on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for maven project folder structure

Answer (score 0):

src/main/resources/some/java/package

Maven will put anything under *src/main/resources* in the root of the jar so `src/main/resources/my/package/icons`
will end up in `<jar-root>/my/package/icons`